# How to install opencv on raspbian jessie Lite?

Tags: python, opencv, raspbian-lite

I am totally new to raspbian Lite and not know how to install opencv on this os. I need this for my school project which is written in python. I am trying this https://gist.github.com/willprice/c216fcbeba8d14ad1138 but when I run this script, 
this is giving many errors that I am unable to understand.

Comment: And you have installed Jessie not Stretch?

Comment: I have installed Raspbian Stretch Lite that does not have any gui.

Comment: That was my concern, you didn't read the title "Installing OpenCV 3.1 on Raspbian Jessie"!

Answer (score 3):

Being two years old, that script has issues such as tying to an older version of OpenCV. Rather than downloading from Itseez's GitHub repo you're better off installing via the Raspbian package repositories.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-opencv
```